# How to pass an integer array testng.xml

Tags: java, testng, functional-testing

I need to pass an integer array in my testng.xml file because I'm using it as my config file to run multiple tests on a method I wrote, to make it data driven.

this method:

```
@Test(groups="runnable")
@Parameters({"fName","lName","childAges"})
public void test(String firstName, String lastName, Integer[] childAges);
```

And in my testng.xml file:

```
<test name="WyomingComplex4Kids (Positive)"> 
    <parameter name="fName" value="John"/> 
    <parameter name="lName" value="Johnson"/>  
    <parameter name="childAges" value="{10,7,3,6}"/> 
    <parameter name="server" value="https://example.server.com/app/someRoute"/>
    <parameter name="port" value="443"/>
    <groups>  
        <run> 
            <include name="runnable"/>  
        </run> 
    </groups> 
    <classes> 
            <class name = "com.somecompany.test.EligibilityComplex1"/> 
    </classes> 
</test>
```

takes in an integer array which contains child ages, this doesn't seem to work. I am new to testng and testing in general. Can somebody help me here? I heard of using a dataprovider tp pass complex objects (i.e. like an array or list) but I am unable to understand how it works or how I can use it in my test. So any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no pattern specified in testng that {"sdf","sdf"} would get converted to array.  You will get a Unsupported type parameter error.  Refer code (convertType method ) [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.0.1/org/testng/internal/Parameters.java#Parameters.convertType%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29).  Only basic datatypes get converted.

If you want to convert it to an array, you need to split and convert in array.

A dataprovider just helps you to run the same test with different data.  In that case as well, if you are say reading from an excel all your data, you would still need to create the array through code.

Comment: You just need to read as string, use the split method and then parse into Int each value.  Change Integer[] to String in your method test - remove the {} from your parameter value in xml.  Use childAges.split(","), which would give as array and then loop through and parseInt.